# removing digit (zero) of a column and create a new column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, leading-zero

For example if I have

```
  ID rout
1  1 0123
2  2 0245
3  3 0789
4  4 0963
5  5 6779
6  6  056
7  7  zxc
8  8  asd
9  9  1234
```

I wonder how I can remove only the first digit of the `rout` column for observations with 4 characters and  only when it (the first character) is zero, and create a column (`rout2`) like below:

```
   ID rout rout2
1  1 0123   123
2  2 0245   245
3  3 0789   789
4  4 0963   963
5  5 6779  6779
6  6  056   056
7  7  zxc   zxc
8  8  asd   asd
9  9  1234  1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit after discussion in the comments

In order to remove *only* the first digit when it is zero, and only for 4-digit alphanumeric values, you can do

```
data$rout2 <- ifelse(nchar(data$rout) == 4, sub("^[0]", "", data$rout), data$rout)
```

Output

```
#   ID rout rout2
# 1  1 0123   123
# 2  2 0245   245
# 3  3 0789   789
# 4  4 0963   963
# 5  5 6779  6779
# 6  6  056   056
# 7  7  zxc   zxc
# 8  8  asd   asd
# 9  9 1234  1234
```

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the question as i noticed there is another condition. Hope someone can help out.

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer with the additional information